# Read a csv file from a bash scripting file

Tags: linux, bash, csv, terminal

in a folder, I have 2 files. Valuation.csv and another file myScript.sh

My CSV file has 10 lines and 5 columns. I have tried to read it multiple times but it never worked. This is what I have tried as code inside my myScript.sh:

First try:

```
#!/bin/bash

    while read -r line do
        field1=$(echo $line | awk -F'|' '{printf "%s", $1}' | tr -d '"')
        field2=$(echo $line | awk -F'|' '{printf "%s", $2}' | tr -d '"')

        echo $field1 $field2 done < $Valuation.csv
```

Result: /myScript.sh: line 10: .csv: No such file or directory

Second try:

```
cat Valuation.csv|while read line   do
read -d, col1 col2 < <(echo $line)
echo "I got:$col1|$col2"   done
```

Result: nothing

I am running the file like this:

./myScript.sh

thank you

[Here the csv file opened with excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqLRY.png)

Comment: why not use general purpose scriping languages such as python/perl?

Comment: Hi @James can you provide the content of one file?

Comment: Save the excel worksheet as a `.csv` and post the data as text, not a picture of the spreadheet. Bash can't read a picture of the spreadsheet.

Comment: @James : The variable `Valuation` is empty/undefined. Aside from this, I don't think it is a good idea to process CSV in this way, as it works only with fairly simple CSV files. For instance, the `awk` part does not work if one of the fields contain a (quoted) `|` as value.

Answer (score 1):

here is my file data.csv

```
Site,Post,Subject,User,Status
stackover flow,bash,read csv,James,ok
git,linux,core,Novy,ko
```

in my bash script i have something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=./data.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read site post subject usr status
do
    echo "Site : $site"
    echo "Post : $post"
    echo "Subject : $subject"
    echo "User : $usr"
    echo "Status : $status"
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Output

Site : stackover flow
Post : bash
Subject : read csv
User : James
Status : ok
Site : git
Post : linux
Subject : core
User : Novy
Status : ko

You can give a look [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-read-comma-separated-cvsfile/)

Comment: Thank you, can you show me a picture of your file? are "Site,Post,Subject,User,Status" columns?

Comment: a csv file is a text file with a comma or semicolon separator. The file content is at the begining of the post. Copy it and create your csv file locally.  I hope it is clear the important thing is the "while read site post subject usr status" after that you can use the variable with the "$" plus variable name

Answer (score 1):

James, avoid calling utilities within a loop in bash. That is horribly inefficient. Avoid using a fixed number of fields -- what if another is added? You can read `.csv` data in bash fairly easily by simply using `read -a array...` and setting the *internal field separator* to word-split on a comma (e.g. `IFS=$',\n'`).

For example, writing a script that takes the `.csv` filename to read as the first argument, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i row=0

while IFS=$',\n' read -r -a array; do
    printf "row %d - read %d fields.\n" $((row++)) ${#array[@]}
    for i in "${array[@]}"; do
        printf " %-12s" "$i"
    done
    echo ""
done < "$1"
```

(**note:** while you would in-practice want to handle the entire matter in `awk`, since this appears to be a bash exercise, for short `.csv` files, bash is more than capable)

**Example Data**

(I wasn't going to retype your spreadsheet, so here are the first two rows)

```
$ cat company.csv
Facebook,35587,55800000000,1567988,491000000000,8.80x
Uber,16000,11300000000,706250,120000000000,10.6x
```

Running the script and simply outputting the row count and fields-per-row followed by the field values themselves, you would get:

```
$ bash readcsv.sh company.csv
row 0 - read 6 fields.
 Facebook     35587        55800000000  1567988      491000000000 8.80x
row 1 - read 6 fields.
 Uber         16000        11300000000  706250       120000000000 10.6x
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. I implemented the first script and it is working but the format is totally off. thanks, However, I do not really get what is the purpose of the example data you wrote later on. Do I need to have a line of code with "$ cat Valuation.csv? Should I implement it within the myScrip.sh file?

Comment: You can change the format of the `printf` statement -- I just used a left-justified 12 character *field-width* to ensure even separation between the fields. No need to `cat validation`. The purpose of the data shown is because you posted a PICTURE of your data rather than your actual data. Most people will ignore your question for that reason -- they are not going to re-type your data. I re-typed two lines of it in `.csv` format. You simply provide the `filename.csv` as the first argument to the script. (you can add a read to consume the header row if needed)